# ShortcutManager crash in instant apps

Tags: android, kotlin, android-instant-apps, android-shortcut

When I run my instant app I'm experiencing a crash due to the shortcut feature, please see the image with the stack trace, this is the only thing I can provide as I'm not able to attach the debugger, another problem :(

[image: stacktrace]

```
**GroupApplication.class**
override fun onCreate() {
    ...
    ShortcutsHelper.init(this)
    ShortcutsHelper.addSearchShortcut()
}
```

```
object ShortcutsHelper {
    lateinit var appContext: Context
    lateinit var shortcutManager: ShortcutManager

    fun init(context: Context) {
        this.appContext = context.applicationContext
        this.shortcutManager = context.getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)
    }

    fun addSearchShortcut() {
        val shortcut = ShortcutInfo.Builder(appContext, SEARCH_SHORTCUT_ID)
                .setShortLabel(appContext.getString(R.string.search_shortcut_short_label))
                .setLongLabel(appContext.getString(R.string.search_shortcut_long_label))
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(appContext, R.drawable.ic_search_black))
                .setIntent(GroupHomeActivity.getStartIntent(appContext, NavigationScreen.SEARCH))
                .build()

        shortcutManager.addDynamicShortcuts(listOf(shortcut))
    }
```

I understand that a shortcut does not make any sense in an Instant App, is there a better solution than having all the code related to shortcuts commented when creating an IA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I understand that a shortcut does not make any sense in an Instant App, is there a better solution than having all the code related to
>   shortcuts commented when creating an IA?*

So yes, Instant Apps is restricted from running some APIs for security purposes. There used to be a FAQ page for it that indicated this, but I can't find it anymore.

But anyways, you don't have to comment it out. You can use:

[/instantapps/PackageManagerCompat.html#isInstantApp()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/PackageManagerCompat.html#isInstantApp())